# RESTful API - different types of children resources

Tags: rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I'm dealing with tree-structred resources. Every `item` resource has `children`. Each `child` type may be `content` resource or `subject` resource - which is determind by the `type_id`. (There could be more children types in the future).

What URI should be used for creating a new child for an item?

```
POST /api/items/<item_id>/children
```

(deliver the `type_id` via the JSON)

OR:

```
POST /api/items/<item_id>/children/contents
POST /api/items/<item_id>/children/subjects
```

OR: redirection according to the `type_id` to:

```
POST /api/contents
POST /api/subjects
```

And then using the GUID of the new resource for creating the hierarchy connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your children have an attribute named `type` which can be `subjects` or `contents`, you can treat that as any other attribute, e.g. a gender that can be male or female.

Ideally, you would create a new child with

```
POST /api/items/<item_id>/children

{
  "some_value": 50
  "type": "subject",
}
```

or

```
POST /api/items/<item_id>/children

{
  "some_value": 134
  "type": "content",
}
```

No need to make a confusing endpoint for a simple attribute. If you'd do this for the `type` attribute, you might as well do it for all the other attributes as well, leading to a great many more endpoints pointing to basically the same resources, that is not something you want.

Later you can fetch them by type, for example getting all subjects would be

```
GET /api/items/<item_id>/children?type=subject
```